# random characters appearing when site is rendered

Tags: html, encoding, ascii

On a couple sites I've made random ASCII characters have been appearing in the middle of the document. It's always been on test sites and has never been a problem until my most recent project for a client that it just appeared on.  They aren't displayed in the development environment I use (aptana 3), but then appear both on screen and in the source code when viewed in a browser.
I've looked around and it looks like others have had the issue but I haven't been able to find any real solution. I tried messing with the text-encoding but nothing changed. Has anyone been able to solve this issue?

Comment: @flem absolutely. www.oryxwebstudio.com/saloncruz/#contact. next to the send button

Comment: I don't see it in FF14, IE9, or Chrome22 in W7. What is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try saving your file as UTF-8?
2. Did you verify that your file is actually saved as UTF-8?
   A Linux command to check the file type is:

   `file -i filename.html`
3. Did you verify the content-header being sent from the webserver?
4. Is any of the text coming from a database?
5. You could also try adding the following meta string:

   `<meta charset="utf-8">`

With your example site: http://www.oryxwebstudio.com/saloncruz/#contact

Maybe I'm blind but I do not see any invalid characters in IE, Firefox or Chrome. Here is a screenshot of Firefox:

[image: contact form screenshot]